# Swift UITest Can not find collectionview inside of tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, uitest

I have a "collectionView" inside of a "tableViewCell" and at XCTest I can not access this "collectionview" or its "cells". here is my code to access this "collectionview". Also I used accessibilityIdentifier but there is nothing change. I can access "tableViewCell" but can not to "collectionView"

```
app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 7).collectionViews.element(boundBy: 0).cells.element(boundBy: 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the reason you cannot get the collectionViewCell is because in the collectionViewCell, there are some gesture responders such as a button. If there is no such subView or some dumb one like a label, still you can get the collectionViewCells as the following:

```
  let collectionViewsQuery = XCUIApplication().tables.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 1).collectionViews // the second table cell 

   let element = collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 3).children(matching: .other).element // the fourth cell

     let element2 = collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 4).children(matching: .other).element // the fifth cell ,
```

etc ..

However, if there is a button in any cell, you can not get the cell directly:

```
  let tablesQuery = XCUIApplication().tables
  let cell = tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 1) // the second table cell

  let button = cell.children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 0) // the button which lies at any of collectionCell and not defined.
```

Hope this answers your question why not getting the collection cell. Actually, you can refer the cell first then try to refer the button later by two steps.